# A question linked with concept of Lie derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a Riemannian 3-manifold. We introduce a function $t$ on $M$ such that the two dimensional surfaces "$t=\text{constant}$" in $M$ are
nested topological 2-spheres with the innermost surface reducing to a point. For each value of $t$ let us assume that $S$ is one such surface and $\eta_a = \nabla_a t$ denotes the normal to $S$. The unit normal is then given by $n_a = (\eta \cdot \eta)^{-1/2}\eta_a$. Let $\xi^a:= un^a$ has the property that $\xi^a\nabla_a t = 1$.

I would like to show that in this case, the rate of change of any quantity related to $S$ with respect to $t$ is its Lie derivative by $\xi^a$.

All my efforts are failed, any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When you write $\xi^a = u n^a$, did you mean to write $u n_a$? And what is $u$?

Comment: And can you clarify what you mean by "the rate of change of any quantity with respect to $t$"? Suppose that $f: M \to \mathbb R$ is a function on $M$. (That seems like a good notion of "quantity" -- a real value at each point.) What's the meaning of the rate of change of $f$ with respect to $t$ at the point $P \in M$?  I have the suspicion that when you're done, there'll be almost nothing left to prove.

Comment: @John, From the property $\xi^a \nabla_a t=1$ you can easily see that $u=(\eta^a \eta_a)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: @John, Quantities related to $S_c$ (2-surface t=c) change with respect to $t$, for example its extrinsic curvature.

Comment: @SepidehBakhoda: This only seems to make sense if you are talking about quantities associated with an entire surface; i.e. a function of the real variable $t$. Is this correct? If the quantity is allowed to vary over each surface, then the time derivative is not well defined without specifying exactly how individual points in the surface move. (A common choice here would be to have them move in the normal direction.) So either you need to specify that the quantity is a function of $t$ alone, or you need to provide extra information about the exact paths taken by points in the surfaces.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis, You are right. Quantities mentioned in the question are exactly functions of the real variable $t$. I made a mistake in the second comment where I wrote "its extrinsic curvature" instead of "its mean curvature". Thank you.
Now, can you help me to solve the question?

Comment: @SepidehBakhoda: this only makes sense when the $S_t$ are constant mean curvature, of course. Answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment I've determined that the precise statement you are looking for is $$f'(t(p)) = \mathcal L_\xi (f \circ t)(p)$$ where $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $p$ is any point on one of the surfaces $S_t$.

All we need is the property $dt(\xi) = \xi^a \nabla_a t = 1$ along with the chain rule: the Lie derivative of a scalar function is just the standard derivative of functions, so $$\mathcal L_\xi (f \circ t) (p) = d(f \circ t)_p(\xi_p) = df_{t(p)} \left( dt_p(\xi_p)\right)=f'(t(p))\cdot1.$$